# How can set Bit type input parameter optional set false by default

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a stored procedure that will have a BIT type parameter that 
will be optional. If that parameter is not included then it should return 
all values (1 and 0). I've put together a sample SP that is working below but I am wondering if 
there is a cleaner way to handle this situation.   By default value will be 0(If that parameter is not included).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetItems] 
@IsInsert Bit = NULL
AS 
BEGIN 
IF(@IsInsert IS NOT NULL )
BEGIN
----Some Logic here
END

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAke default as 0

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetItems] 
@IsInsert Bit = 0
AS 
BEGIN 
IF(@IsInsert==0)
BEGIN
----Some Logic here
END

END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all records if the parameter is null.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetItems] 
@IsInsert Bit = NULL
AS 
BEGIN 

SELECT * FROM [Table]
WHERE @IsInsert IS NULL OR IsInsert = @IsInsert 

END
```